# I haven't seen him since I've been in London

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> "I haven't seen him since I've been in London".

What does this sentence above mean?

Does it mean

> I haven't seen him since I moved to London

or

> I haven't seen him since I left London?

Thank you.

Comment: Not the second option: the original would be "since I *was* in London." It can also mean "I haven't seen him *because* I've been in London."

Comment: "since I've been in London" does not only mean "since I moved to London". It could mean "since I arrived in London for a vacation or short stay".

Comment: If it could mean "since I arrived in London for a vacation or short stay", I think I'm out of London now. So, my second explanation could be right.

Comment: If I arrived in London at 8 AM today, and it is now 12:30 PM, I could grammatically say "I have not seen a red bus since I have been in London".

Comment: That would be inferred from the context, which isn't given. The statement, as you say, is ambiguous.

Comment: So, there're at least three scenarios and four explanations: 1, I moved to London, and I'm still living here. *since I've been in London* means since I moved here. 2, I moved to London, but I've now left. *since I've been in London* means since I left. 3. I arrived in London for a short stay. *since I've been in London* means since my arrival. 4. I arrived in London for a short stay. *since I've been in London* means since my departure. Which is/are correct explanation(s)? –

Comment: 'Since I've been in London' applies only while you are still in London. Your scenarios 1 and 3 are correct.

Comment: It could mean either, or even, "*I haven't seen him **because** I've been in London.*"

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this would be the former ( "I haven't seen him since I moved to London" ).

The "I have been" part implies the speaker is still in London (or at least, still living there) and so the person has not been seen since this started, I.E. since they moved to London.

If the speaker wanted to say "since I left London" then they would be more likely to have said this, or "... since I *went to* London" (implying that the event completed in the past)

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence does not actually specify, and could be either.  It doesn't specify a lot of things, actually.  We could expand this sentence to read like this:

> There was a time I was in London. I am not specifying whether I lived there, or was just visiting.  I am not saying whether I was there for a short time, or a long time.  I am not saying I left recently, or a long time ago.
>
> I saw him at some point when I was in London.  I am not saying whether I saw him before London, or if I saw him once or more than once.
>
> I haven't seen him at any point after the time I was in London.

Comment: Your answer sounds like *since I left London.* But you also say it could be either. So, what is exactly your position?